# How to create an installer to deploy a full .net solution

Tags: .net, web-applications, installation

I have a solution that needs to be packed up in an installer and consists of the following:

- 4 iis websites (1 mvc, 1 webAPI, 1 wcf, 1 angular enabled site)
- 1 windows service
- MySQL server with 2 databases

Right now I have been given a bat file (along with a resources folder) that is to run on a vanilla WinServer2012 or later and does the following:

- Install IIS 7 role
- Setup Microsoft .NET Framework (installer file bundled in resources)
- Register Microsoft .NET Framework
- Setup Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (installer file bundled in resources)
- Install MySQL (installer file bundled in resources)
- Install MySQL Connector (installer file bundled in resources)
- Run mySQL scripts to create databases (script files bundled in resources)
- Opens web.config files of sites one by one in editor to be edited regarding connection strings and other application settings
- Copy site files to folders of C:\inetpub (site files bundled in resources)
- Encrypt connection stings
- Create windows Service user
- Install windows Service and assign user to it (service files bundled in resources)
- Setup websites and application pools

I need to make a more user friendly deployment application and replace the batch file running on console, but I dont have experience in tools like InstallShield or AdvancedInstaller and I dont know if these will provide me with such capabilities.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

Both tools you mentioned have support to install websites, windows services and database servers and run sql scripts. On the Advanced Installer web site they have a section with [tutorials](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorials.html) where you can learn how to build your setup package.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted, but do you know if these can offer all the rest tasks I mention in my questions?

Comment: From my experience I think Advanced Installer matches all of your requirements excepting the "Encrypt connection stings". For this task you could create your own small app which encrypts the strings and run it during installation as a custom action.